# cut and paste range not working when filtered

Tags: excel, vba

I have a a sheet of data, and I want to filter based on the start of the policy number, and then I want to move all of the BFL policies after PFL policies. Row 1 contain all of the headers. My policy number starts with either PFL or BFL.

The reason why I can't sort Z-A directly because the raw data starts with BFL001 to BFL999 then PFL001 to PFL999 so sorting Z-A will get PFL999 first, but I want to just move everything from BFL001 to BFL999 after PFL001, like simple cut and paste. My range varies each month so I am using 001 to 999 to show you how my raw data is displayed.

After I run my current VBA module, it starts from row 1000 and from BFL001 to PFL999 which is not what I want. I need to start from PFL001 to PFL999 and then BFL001 to BFL999, and with no blank rows in between.

I am not sure if I can use partial search or use text like to find policies that starts with BFL then cut and paste to last row + 1. Not sure which way is faster.

```
Sub test()
    Dim LR1 As Long
    LR1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Combined")
        With .Range("A2:AU" & LR1)
             .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="BFL" & "*"
             .Cut Range("A" & LR1 + 1)
        End With
             .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A neat trick with VBA is that you can reference certain cells that share a property using `.SpecialCells` in your case you'd want to use `xlCellTypeVisible` but there are many others that can be used.

The trick here is to do the cut manually. You can't cut cells that aren't right next to each other, but you can copy and paste them. So the idea is to paste the BFL cells below the PFL cells and then empty out the original cells and clean up the white spaces. After you apply the autofilter you can tell excel to only look at the visible cells within the same range that you specified before, so you don't get anything extra. This is important because when you go to clear all the visible cells, you don't want to accidentally clear the cells you just pasted below.

When you're cleaning up blank cells it's important to go from the bottom up because other wise you could run into indexing issues. You'll also notice that I use `.entirerow` so that it deletes the entire row instead of just the first column.

To show all of the data you simply go `Worksheet.showalldata`, **BUT** you need to check if there is even an autofilter applied to the sheet. Occasionally when you perform operations such as clearing cells, it'll turn off the autofilter, so it's best to check whether its still there or not so your macro doesn't throw an error at you.

One last tiny thing, although you're not wrong, it's not necessary to concatenate a string with the wildcard `*` you could simply have them within the same string. eg. `"BFL*"` vs `"BFL" & "*"` just saves a bit of time on typing.

```
Sub test()
    Dim LR1 As Long
    Dim BFLRange As Range
    LR1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Combined")
        With .Range("A2:AU" & LR1)
             .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="BFL" & "*"

             Set BFLRange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
             BFLRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("A" & LR1 + 1)
        End With
        BFLRange.Clear

        For i = LR1 To 2 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next i
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This snippet follows @SJR's suggestion where you delete the entire used region containing BFL. The reason I've disabled alerts is because there's just a little text box that pops up asking if you're sure you want to delete the sheet rows. By turning it off, it doesn't require any user input. It's good to note that by deleting the cells at once, it'll speed up the macro drastically if you're working with a large amount of data. Thanks again @SJR.

```
Sub test()
    Dim LR1 As Long
    Dim BFLRange As Range
    LR1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Combined")
        With .Range("A2:AU" & LR1)
             .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="BFL" & "*"

             Set BFLRange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
             BFLRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("A" & LR1 + 1)
        End With

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        BFLRange.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'        For i = LR1 To 2 Step -1
'            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then
'                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
'            End If
'        Next i
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Your codes work great, just what I need.

Comment: Good stuff, but couldn't you delete the range in one go?

Comment: @SJR I've actually never tried that before, but it looks like you can! I'll edit my answer to include the code with that as well

Comment: Thank you, the revised codes have speed up drastically since I have more than 100k of data.